How to show another domain page inside one domain path?
Let's say i have x.com domain and this is my main domain. i have another domain called y.com to show my users the contents. The thing is i want to use only x.com to show y.com contents too within x.com/y. So i want to show the page from y.com inside of domain path in x.com/y.
y.com is on different server than x.com
is this possible to do?
in my x.com, i use wordpress and cloudflare, i already configured my x.com apache webserver  like this
ProxyPass /y/ https://y.com/
ProxyPassReverse /y/ https://y.com/

<Location /y/>
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain y.com
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /y/
</Location>

But nothing is happening, it still getting 404 page instead of getting the y.com page. What should i do? much thanks.
